# External Hard Disk Drive: "Waiting for "TOSHIBA EXT" to become connected" (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: backup, external-hdd, accessibility

Foreword: Whilst similar, none of the questions / answers already posted have addressed my problem.

- I am running Ubuntu 18 with "Déjà Dup Backup Tool".
- I have a Toshiba 1.8 TiB ext. hard disk drive attached via USB (USB-3).
- I am able to copy files from my (internal) hard disk to this ext HDD.
- I am NOT able to back-up successfully.  When I try to backup I get the following response: "Storage Location not available  - waiting for 'TOSHIBA EXT' to become available".
- I have run GParted and it shows it as " /dev/sdd " with a key symbol next to it
- filesystem: ntfs
- mount point: /media/myname/24B133B25E747DF6

I should be MOST grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution: using Ubuntu 18:
1. Connect the EDD (via USB);
2. Open "Disks" and select the EDD - making sure it is the EDD you want - and not your (internal hard drive!);
3. Make sure it is mounted;
4. Select the gears icon and then "Format Partition"
5. Used following parameters for format (under 'Partition Type'): W95 FAT32 (LBA) (Bootable)  /  'Contents': FAT (32-bit version)

And that did the trick.

I only had one sector / partition - I suppose if you had more than one, you should erase all of them before beginning the formatting process.

Comment: I thought that you had a ntfs filesystem on that external HDD? FAT32 is probably not the right choice. It should use a GPT partition table, and ext4 or ntfs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Well, it is working fine at the moment so, as it is "not broke - I ain't gonna fix-it" !    I don't fully understand your answer - my fault, not yours (I am a newbee) - so won't be trying it for the moment (as it is presently working OK).  Thank you once again for your time.

Comment: Are you using this as a data drive under Ubuntu, or Windows, or both? Since it's a 2T external drive, it should be formatted with a GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive) and then a ext4 or ntfs partition should be created... not FAT32.

Comment: I only use it for Ubuntu. Next time I have a similar problem I will do it the way you suggest. Thank you very much for your time and expertise. Sincerely, Duncan